# Find $z_n$ divergent, so that $|z_n|$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

Do you know a divergent series or sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ ($z_n\in\mathbb{C}$), which absolut value $(|z_n|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges?

I was not able to find one... only in the other direction (convergent becomes divergent), e.g. $\sum_n(-1)\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: This cannot exist - look at the relationship between absolute convergence and convergence.

Comment: Do you mean **series**, as in $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty z_n\;$ , or **sequence**, as what you did write: $\;\{z_n\}\;$?

Comment: As pointed out, convergence of a series is necessary for absolute convergence in a complete space.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I meant indeed sequence (my native language is German), but I would be also interested in series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually meant **sequence**, try $\;z_n:=(-1)^n\;{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$ ....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/914520)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Oh, this **does** provide an answer to the question as asked. Read carefully...And also a comment was left that the OP completely disregarded.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant sequence. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonMueller Then **this** is the answer you want, though the other answer has been upvoted and is correct within the realm of *series* ...

Comment: Yes I saw it and voted accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

We know that absolute convergence of a series (in Banach space) implies convergence. Hence you cannot find a series which is absolutely convergent and not convergent.